# Java: can you change the value of the same string every time it loops?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I'm doing a very basic calculator program in java that asks for the users input, and based on what he inputs(if "add" or else) either adds up the two values or subtracts them.

The problem is, i want it to loop, so after every equation is finished and the result is displayed, it asks the user again if he wants to add or subtract. Is there any way, without using arrays, to change the value of the String each time the program loops?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i<999; i++) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to add or subtract?");
            String answer1 = input.nextLine();
            if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                System.out.println("Enter first value");
                int addv1 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter second value");
                int addv2 = input.nextInt();
                int ans = addv1 + addv2;
                System.out.println("The answer is: " + ans);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter first value");
                int subv1 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter second value");
                int subv2 = input.nextInt();
                int ans2 = subv1 - subv2;
                System.out.println("The answer is: " +ans2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java String is immutable. All mutating operation provided by String API creates another instance with "mutated" value.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Answer (score 3):

Each time you assign a value to the String variable, `answer1`, it refers to a new String object, and the reference to the old String object is lost. So, no, you are not changing the value of the same String (and you can't, since String is immutable), you are changing the String that the variable is referring to.

Comment: This does not address the problem at all.  Did you just see "change" and "String" in the question and jump right to an answer without looking at the whole question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what your problem is, but I suspect it's this:  Each line you input ends with a "new line" character.  The `nextInt` functions will retrieve the next integer from the input, but they do not "consume" the newline character.  Therefore, when you go back to the top of the loop and say

```
    String answer1 = input.nextLine();
```

it will give you everything on the *current* line, up to the newline character.  What this actually means is that it will give you an empty string, since that's all that's left on the current line after the previous integer is consumed.

If your program isn't working, try putting an additional `nextLine()` at the end of the loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<999; i++) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to add or subtract?");
        String answer1 = input.nextLine();
        if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
           // etc.
        }
        input.nextLine();  // ADD THIS
    }
```

This will "consume" the leftover newline character, so that when you go back to the top, it will actually let the user enter another line.

**P.S.** See David's answer, which gives you a much better way of deciding when to leave the loop.  (But you still need to add the `nextLine.`)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but this is essentially what I needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after you call `int subv2 = input.nextInt();`, the buffer has a newline character left, so that the following loop iteration, `input.nextLine()`is just an empty line. To fix this add a call to nextLine() after each iteration.

Comment: Typo: `input.nextLine`, not `answer1.nextLine`.

Answer (score 0):

While the other posters are correct that "strings are immutable", you can achieve the effect you want with an "infinite" do..while loop that checks for a condition to `break` out of it, like so:

```
do {
        System.out.println("Do you want to add, subtract, or quit?"); // changed this
        String answer1 = input.nextLine();
        if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            // check for "quit" value, and call break if that's what the user wants
            break;
        }
        if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            System.out.println("Enter first value");
            int addv1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second value");
            int addv2 = input.nextInt();
            int ans = addv1 + addv2;
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + ans);
        } else { // this will catch anything that's not "add" or "quit".  You might want to guard against that
            System.out.println("Enter first value");
            int subv1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second value");
            int subv2 = input.nextInt();
            int ans2 = subv1 - subv2;
            System.out.println("The answer is: " +ans2);
        }
    } while (true); // will repeat forever until `break` is called
```

Comment: This does not fix the actual problem.  However, it's definitely useful to point out that another way of terminating the loop is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's good practise to have a way for the user to terminate the loop.