# for loop class assignment gone wrong

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm in a class in college and we're doing Java.  This is only my 4th class so I'm super new (be nice).  My problem, hopefully my only one is that this will actually run but, after the user is asked to input the number of students grades you'd like to enter.  It then goes into the for loop and asks the next two questions at the same time and then I get an error.  I'm trying to figure out how to get it to ask the questions separately but I'm not having any luck.  Someone had suggested io.console but I don't think we're allowed to use that, we haven't learned it yet.  I came across hasNext but I'm not really sure how it works, and the more I read on it the more it confuses me.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 
/*Write a java program that prompts the user to enter the number of students and then each student’s name and score, 
 * and finally displays the student with highest score and the student with the second- highest score. 
 * You are NOT allowed to use ‘Arrays’ for this problem (as we have not covered arrays yet).
 * 
 * HINT: You do not need to remember all the inputs. You only need to maintain variables for max and second max
 *  scores and corresponding names. Whenever you read a new input, you need to compare it to the so far established 
 *  max & second max scores and change things accordingly. */
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentScore {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String studentName="", highName="", secondHighName="";
    int score=0, highScore=0, secondHighScore=0;
    int count;
    int classSize;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many students' grades do you want to enter? ");
    classSize = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < classSize.hasNext; i++)  {
        System.out.print("Please enter the students name? ");
        studentName = scan.hasNextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter the students score? ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
    }
        if (score >= secondHighScore) {
            secondHighScore = highScore;
            secondHighName = highName;
            highScore = score;
            highName = studentName;

        }
    }   

    System.out.print("Student with the highest score: " + highName + " " + highScore);
    System.out.print("Student with the second highest score: " + secondHighName + " " + secondHighScore);

}

}

Comment: `classSize` is `int`.  What `classSize.hasNext` could possibly be?  I think you need to go back to the book used for the course and find some code samples there.

Comment: `hasNextLine` doesn't return another line, it tests to see if there is another line.  So it returns a `boolean`, not a `String`.  Also see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871872/java-can-you-change-the-value-of-the-same-string-every-time-it-loops/24872201#24872201 because you are about to run into the same problem.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand now.  Any chance you could give me a quick easy example of how hasNextLine would work?  Also, I'm reading through your other post to see what other problem you're talking about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to check if the recieved score is greater than the second score and if that score if greater than the highest score. Secondly replace `studentName = scan.hasNextLine()` with `studentName = scan.nextLine()`. Also create a new `Scanner`.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String studentName="", highName="", secondHighName="";
    int score=0, highScore=0, secondHighScore=0;
    int classSize;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many students' grades do you want to enter? ");
    classSize = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)  {
        System.out.println("Please enter the student #" + (i + 1) + "'s name? ");
        //new Scanner plus changed to nextLine()
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        studentName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the student #" + (i + 1) + " score? ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
        if(score >= highScore){
            secondHighName = highName;
            secondHighScore = highScore;
            highName = studentName;
            highScore = score;
        } else if(score >= secondHighScore && score < highScore){
            secondHighName = studentName;
            secondHighScore = score;
        }
    }
    scan.close();   
    System.out.println("Student with the highest score: " + highName + " " + highScore);
    System.out.println("Student with the second highest score: " + secondHighName + " " + secondHighScore);

}
```

Comment: Ok so adding the new scan=new Scanner(system.in) will allow for the questions to be asked separately?  Also, why the i + 1 in the print statements?  won't the i++ in the for loop handle that?  Also, is this the only time you would need to use scan.close();?  Thanks so much for the help too, all of you!

Comment: The i + 1 is to make it easier to read the output because the first student would be Student #0 and the second student would be Student #1 and it would be confusing. As for closing the scanner it shouldn't cause a resource leak but better safe than sorry. So you should close it at the end of the for loop.

Comment: "&& score < highscore" in the second **if** is redundant because this is the **else** part of the first **if**, so it is not greater than or equal to highscore, therefore _must_ be less than highscore.

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference does it.